# Redefining a corrupted reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

```
class A
{
};

int main()
{
    A *a= new A(); // variable "a" must be pointer, I can't edit this line

    A& b = *a; //b must be a reference

    delete a; //deletion
    a= new A(); //re-definition

    //b is now corrupted.
}
```

In a piece of code that I have to work with, a pointer to an object of class A is created  and  a reference to this pointer too.

For some reasons, I have to delete the pointer and re-defined it. How can I get b to work again ?

Comment: You can't. 4321

Comment: `*a = new A()` after `delete a` is illegal.

Comment: you can, if you declare `b` as `struct { A &_; } b = { *a };` (access  needs `b._`). The re-definition works like `new (&b) decltype(b){*a}`. If you like this comment, please upvote.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb It says "b must be a reference", not a struct.

Comment: More than that, `*a = new A()` is a compile time error.

Comment: * a = new A() was a typo

Comment: @user1482030 I have a solution which involves access `_.b`. Then b is a reference.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb please detail your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, subject to some constraints:

```
A* a = new A(); // variable "a" must be pointer, I can't edit this line
A& b = *a;      // b must be a reference


a->~A();        // destroy first object
new (a) A();    // create second, new object in its place

delete a;       // destroy second object and release memory
```

The constraints are if `A` contains non-static const data members, you cannot use `b` after the reconstruction.

(Starting with C++17, you *can* reuse a reconstructed object even if it has const members by using some  extra acrobatics: `A& b2 = *std::launder(a);` But you still cannot reuse `b` as is.)

Answer (score 0):

in your code you are not using a reference to a pointer, to do so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{

    int* ptrA   = new int(77);
    int*& rPtrA = ptrA; // this a reference to a pointer

    cout << "ptrA: "   << ptrA  << endl;
    cout << "*ptrA: "  << *ptrA << endl;
    cout << "rPtrA: "  << rPtrA << endl;
    cout << "*rPtrA: " << *rPtrA << endl;

    delete ptrA;
    ptrA = NULL;

    cout << "ptrA: "  << ptrA  << endl;
//  cout << "*ptrA: " << *ptrA << endl;  // cause runtme error
    cout << "rPtrA: " << rPtrA << endl;
//  cout << "*rPtrA: " << *rPtrA << endl;// cause runtme error

    ptrA = new int(100);

    cout << "ptrA: "  << ptrA  << endl;
    cout << "*ptrA: " << *ptrA << endl;
    cout << "rPtrA: " << rPtrA << endl;
    cout << "*rPtrA: " << *rPtrA << endl;

    delete rPtrA; // delete pointer through its reference
    rPtrA = NULL;

    cout << "ptrA: "  << ptrA  << endl;
//  cout << "*ptrA: " << *ptrA << endl; // runtime error
    cout << "rPtrA: " << rPtrA << endl;
//  cout << "*rPtrA: " << *rPtrA << endl; // runtime error

    return 0;
}
```

&* is used for reference to pointer not just &.
a reference is a just another pseudonym to a variable so whatever the variable changes the reference changes also.

a reference to a pointer REFERS to the POINTER'S ADDRESS not the address the pointer stores (value of pointer).

in your code you used a reference to the value(what pointer stores not the pointer itself) the pointer points to